# cocoa touch - view frames

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

my problem is the following:

I have an UIViewController initialized in a NIB. In this nib, I have created another UIView (call it view XY) and linked it to an IBOutlet inside the UIViewController.

I have then added some UIImageView area exclusively via code and added them to view XY.

This is a portion of code:

```
-(void) displayImage{
     XYImageView=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
     [imageContainer insertSubview:XYImageView atIndex:0];
     [XYImageView setFrame:imageContainer.frame];
     //some code that loads an UIImage into the XY view
     XYImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    }
```

Problem is that my image appears resized correctly, BUT it is collocated outside the XYImageView area. I cannot understand why.

Also, if I try to log the view's size and origin, I get all 0's.

Maybe I am missing something?

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frame property defines view position in coordinate system of its parent, so your `xyimageview` gets the same coordinates as its parent has in its superview. To set child view completely fill its superview try to do the following (i.e. use `bounds` property, not `frame`):

```
 [XYImageView setFrame:imageContainer.bounds];
```